# In production , How architecture of pods defined?

Tags: kubernetes

If i have 2 tier application. web tier and database tier. Then how we can build pod architecture.?

1. By creating 2  container of web and database in single pod, and make replicas of it to make load.
   OR
2. creating namespace of web and database. Creating one web container in one pod and make replicas  of it in web namespace and also assigning service for it. Also one database container in one pod and make replicas  of it in database namespace and also assigning service for it. database service is access by web tier. we only expose web-service to external world.

If there any other method is there, then pls share it.

Thank you for your answer..

I want best method for creation of pods for web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should almost always implement this by creating a Deployment for your application and a StatefulSet for your database.  Both need matching Services.

If you think about the database component, it has persistent storage.  Depending on the database you're using you may not be able to run more than one copy of it (PostgreSQL, MySQL) or you may need to do special work to get multiple replicas to work together.  If you bundle the application and database together into a single Pod then you can't scale up the application without also creating a new database, and then each replica gets a different database, so you'll have data-consistency problems.  Separate Pods also means you can upgrade the application without having to restart the database.

In most cases you shouldn't create bare Pods.  Your now-stateless application should be managed by a Deployment, which supports multiple (identical) replicas and zero-downtime upgrades.  Your database should be in a StatefulSet, which manages per-replica storage (each replica gets its own PersistentVolumeClaim) and has different upgrade rules to avoid sharing storage.

I'll raise the possibility of using an out-of-cluster database as well.  Databases have special requirements on disk size and speed and backups that other components may not, and it may make sense to run an external database not in Kubernetes.

It's your choice whether to use one namespace or several.  On the product I work on, we've found it most manageable to have a separate namespace per application component in production, but to deploy into a single namespace in developer-oriented setups.  This mostly affects what some Kubernetes-internal relationships can use (a Service only points at Pods in its own namespace) and DNS names, but doesn't really affect your main application flow.